# Setting MaxLength on TextBox depending upon DropDownList selection?

Tags: asp.net, .net, textbox

I have a TextBox that is displayed depending upon a selection in a DropDownList.  The default behavior of the textbox is `Visible="false"`.  The MaxLength value need to vary depending upon the selection in the DropDownList.  Note that occasionally the TextBox will not be displayed.

I have provided the markup below.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlList_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbOther" runat="server" Visible="false" OnPreRender="tbOther_PreRender"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlList" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm still working through the way to address this issue, but would it be possible to save the value for the MaxLength on the DropDownList and then, in the code behind, use that value to set the MaxLength on the TextBox?  Since I have the dropdown in an UpdatePanel and am using AutoPostBack it seems that this should be possible but I don't know how/where the value could be stored.

Comment: I think it would be quicker and more efficient to set the text box's max length using JS instead of doing a postback.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You can do this.

```
void Page_Load()
{
    tbOther.MaxLength = Int32.Parse(ddlList.SelectedValue);
}
```

The value is automatically stored in the page's [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) so you don't have to worry about that at all.

Comment: You're going to need to cast or convert ddlList.SelectedValue

Comment: I essentially have the same code in my Page_Load() but it does not appear to work.  I do a "View Source" and don't see the maxlength value.  I should have mentioned this is within a user control which may be the problem?

Comment: Note that if I refresh the page (to cause the postback again) the value is properly set.  This is why I thought the Page_Load() was not a valid solution.  I believe the Page is rendered by the time the Page_Load() executes, but the User Control does not have a "Pre" render event.

Comment: By the way, I have also tried to set the value in the OnPreRender="tbOther_PreRender" listed above.